# Mysterious oneliner template code, any one?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, metaprogramming

I was reading this page :
[C++ Tip: How To Get Array Length](http://www.dev102.com/2009/01/12/c-tip-how-to-get-array-length/). The writer presented a piece of code to know the size of static arrays.

```
template<typename T, int size>
int GetArrLength(T(&)[size]){return size;} // what does '(&)' mean ?
.
.
.
int arr[17];
int arrSize = GetArrLength(arr); // arrSize = 17
```

Could anyone please shed the light on this code, because I couldn't understand how it really works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function is passed a reference (`&`) to an array of type `T`, and size `size`.

Comment: I am sorry but I could not understand why should we pass a reference of an array ? :)

Comment: because that way it doesn't make a copy of the array to pass it in to the function.

Comment: @Goz arrays are not copied in C/C++ when passed, the name of the array is the reference. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @AraK: the array will indeed be passed as a pointer. The code just makes this explicit. It's a needless optimization.

Comment: @outis the problem is that if you take the '(&)' out, the code fails to compile :(

Comment: The only way an array can be passed to a function is as a reference. Arrays can not be passed by value. If you try, it decays to a pointer. And if the function receives a pointer, the array size information has been lost. The only way to make the size information visible to the function is to pass a reference to the array.

Answer (score 1):

sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])

Won't catch errors if the array degrads to a pointer type, but it will still compile!

Templated version is bullet proof.

Answer (score 1):

T(&)[size] is reference to T[size]. If you don't use reference C++ will treat T[size] as T*, and function template parameter deduction would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's tricky.  I don't know either, but if you keep reading down into the comments on that page:

> is essentially
>
> int arr[17]; int arrSize =
>   GetArrLength(arr);
>
> which creates this function:
>
> int GetArrLength(int(&)[17]){return
>   17;}

So & must mean reference like it always does, so it's taking a reference of the array type and the size (second item in the template) is then the size of the incoming array.

Think I'll stick with old

```
sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])
```

Comment: the problem with your sizeof trick is that it fails silently if the array decays to a pointer. Then you get the wrong result, but no errors or warnings. The template trick the OP shows will fail to compile if passed a pointer.

Comment: I agree with Jaif (note: +1): Using the reference-array trick is the right way to extract the size of an array. This is how Visual C++ implements its C++ strcpy_s (and similar) functions. The sizeof will fail silently on C++.